# How to extract a grid layer from GEE image?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, google-earth-engine-python-api, geemap

Recently while working with GEE in python I was trying to slice a Landsat image to get its bands and **grid** for a specific area.

On the first stage I sampled a neighborhood around a point with radius 150 pixels (i.e. 4500 m):

```
neighborhood = image.neighborhoodToArray(kernel=ee.Kernel.square(radius=150, units='pixels'))
data = neighborhood.sampleRectangle(point)
result_dict = data.getInfo()
```

After doing so I managed to obtain an array containing values for each band I selected:

```
array = np.empty((10,301,301))
for i, key in enumerate(bands):
  region = result_dict['properties'][key]
  array[i] = region[0][0][:][:]
```

So my question is **how to get a geographical grid for this data?**

In other words, is it possible to access latitudes and longitudes as a raster layer and extract it?

I know how to do that using rasterio and gdal, but it requires direct download of the data, which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the bands from `ee.Image.pixelLonLat()` to your image.  But getInfo is not the right way to get the pixels.  Check out `ee.data.computePixels()`.  It'll even give you numpy format if you ask for it.

Comment: Thanks for your help! These functions turned out to be really useful=)